# How to integrate cortana skill with my application in android

Tags: android, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

I have one simple **android** application. How do I open my application through **cortana skill**? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Cortana Skills do not support app launch scenarios on Android and ios Cortana app.